# const char* to WCHAR?

Tags: c++

hi I need a WCHAR or some other LPCWSTR for the textout function. I have another function that outputs a string:

```
string run_TypeSt(char op_Sel) {
switch (op_Sel) {
case 'm'://model
{
    searchv_Str = "boatsmodel_s";
    return parseFilestr(42, true);

}
case 't'://type (this is going to be really tricky)
{

}
case 'i'://make
{
    searchv_Str = "boatsmake_s";
}
}
```

parseFilestr just returns a string:

```
string parseFilestr(int start, bool tweak) 
{

//lots of omitted code here
string info_Str = "hello";
return info_Str;//return the requested data
}
```

my header file looks like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
    int parseFilenum(int start, bool tweak);
    int run_Type(char op_Sel);
    std::string parseFilestr(int start, bool tweak);
    std::string run_TypeSt(char op_Sel);
```

The execution looks like this:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string var;

int APIENTRY wWinMain(...)
{
var = run_TypeSt('m');
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(...)
{
 case WM_PAINT:
        {

        TextOut(hdc, 5, 5, var, 6);// issue here, var is not compatible with TextOut. Solutions?
        break;
}
```

The stupid question is, how do I change var to a type that will work with TextOut? Or maybe there is an alternative to textout? Ive been busting my head over this and can't seem to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend reviewing this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-textouta

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: `WCHAR` and `LPCWSTR` are just `wchar_t` and `wchar_t*`. Both can be gotten from a `std::wstring`. If you choose to use a "Unicode character set" in your project, you are also supposed to use `wstring` (as much as possible).

Answer (score 2):

Use `TextOutA` instead. It takes an ANSI string (a `[const] char *`).

That said, read up on Unicode and the options that you have for widechar/char interaction. In the long run, the whole program should probably be written with widechars, except for the bits where you interact with multibyte (or single-byte) file and wire formats.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
std::string FromWideString(const std::wstring& WIDESTRING)
{
   std::string result;
   size_t widelength = WIDESTRING.length();
   char* temp = new char[widelength+2];
   temp[widelength+1]=NULL;
   size_t res = wcstombs(temp, WIDESTRING.c_str(), widelength+1);
   if (res != (size_t) -1)
     result=temp;
   delete temp;
return(result);
  }
```